# Automatic website navigation tools

Tags: automation, web, navigation

I am looking for some automatic website navigation tools to use on a website.

On some websites, one clicks on a button, and then a new form appears. Choose an option, then a new form appears (could be a check box), and so on till the end.  There are several steps. Is there an online tool to automate this, kind of record the flow once, and then I could replay it?

I found one tool: https://www.everystep-automation.com but I think there could be better ones.

Comment: Welcome Nick!  What features are you looking for that the tool you found does not include?  Also, do you have a price range, or are you looking for a gratis tool?  If you will, please answer within your question instead of within this comments section.  Thanks, and again, welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) and its subproject [Selenium IDE](https://selenium.dev/selenium-ide/), the *"Open source record and playback test automation for the web"*.

But be warned: these are  developer tools designed for automated software testing. Selenium Tests are known to be very brittle. Slight changes in the UI make the recorded actions fail.

Comment: I installed the chrome extension for Selenium. I recorded the clicks, but the behavior was entirely random when I ran it. It stops at a point where it could click on the checkbox accurately before. Also, is it possible to run multiple scripts parallelly?